# Retrieving Selected Cell "Position" on Listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I got it to work flawlessly for the **Y** coordinate, here's what I've tried:

```
public Point GetCellPos(MouseEventArgs e){
    ListViewHitTestInfo lit = listview1.HitTest(e.Location);

    Point p = new Point
    {
        X = listview1.Left + lit.Item.Position.X,
        Y = listview1.Top + lit.Item.Position.Y
    };

    return p;
}
```

And for some reason, it won't get me the correct **X** coordinate. As a side note, I didn't put the listview control in a container other than the parent/form, so what could I be doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated, please.

Comment: Out of curiosity what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @FKunecke Thanks for asking. I'm trying to programatically set/move another "editing" controls (e.g. ComboBox, TextBox) on top of the cell's exact position to allow user to edit the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKAY, I solved it!! The key turned out to be in the `Rectangle` prop called `Bound`! I kept on tinkering with the `X, Y` coords ignoring the `Rectangle` which is actually what I was looking for! But anyway, I'm posting my humble snippet for those who might encounter the same problem in the future:

```
private void SetControlOnCell(ListView lv, Control eControl, MouseEventArgs e) {
    ListViewHitTestInfo lit = lv.HitTest(e.Location);

    Point p = new Point
    {
        X = lv.Left + lit.SubItem.Bounds.Left + 1,
        Y = lv.Top + lit.SubItem.Bounds.Top
    };

    int w = (lit.SubItem.Bounds.Left == 0) ? lv.Columns[0].Width : lit.SubItem.Bounds.Width;
    int h = lit.SubItem.Bounds.Height;

    eControl.Location = p;
    eControl.Size = new Size(w, h);

    if (!eControl.Visible) eControl.Visible = true;
    if (eControl.Font != lit.SubItem.Font) eControl.Font = lit.SubItem.Font;
    eControl.Text = lit.SubItem.Text;
    eControl.Focus();        
}
```

And you use it like:

```
private void listview1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    SetControlOnCell(listview1, txtEditValue, e)
}
```

I'm quite happy with this already as it's served the purpose of showing a "pseudo" control on top of a clicked cell (like I wanted it to). However, I'm keeping this question thread open for some better solutions others here may have and be willing to share.

--

**EDIT**: Ok, since no one's turned up -- thread's resolved I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the way I do this in one of my apps is I have a `ContextMenuStrip` that I've made for when the user right-clicks on an item in my `ListView`.  From this, you can customize the menu itself to have controls in it if needed, or simply have it open up a dialog to edit the item properties.

Here's my click handler:

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        var item = listView1.GetItemAt(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
        if (item != null) {
            menuItemSelected.Show(Cursor.Position);
            menuItemSelected.Tag = item.Tag;
        }
    }
}
```

I store item-specific information in the `Tag` property, as this makes it very easy to use across my program.

You can replace `menuItemSelected.Show()` with something to display the control you want at the right location.

Note that this displays it exactly where the user right-clicks on the item, not the top-left corner of the item.  If you want to do that replace `Cursor.Position` with `item.Position`.

Comment: But I need to use controls, like ComboBox/TextBox and put them on the cell's exact location. Using `ContextMenuStrip` would probably help but in my case, I really need to use another controls but `ContextMenuStrip`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Since you've said it, you could say I need to get the control to "emerge on the top-left corner of the cell."

Comment: Ok, please gimme a sec. I'll go and test it and be right back!

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work for me.. The editing control still won't show in the right place.

Comment: I did: `txtEditValue.Location = item.Position;` as you pointed it out but the TextBox never showed up right.